# Show that if $f$ continuous, $f(x_0) = c > 0$, then $\exists$ interval with $x_0$ such that $f(x) > c/2$ for every $x \in I$.

Tags: integration, functions, proof-verification, continuity

I need to show that if $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f(x_0) = c > 0$ for some $x_0 \in [0, 1]$, then there is an interval $I$ containing $x_0$ such that $f(x) > c/2$ for every $x \in I$.

I know that $f$ is Riemann integrable. This is part of a larger question on proving $f(x) = 0$, where $f$ is a continuous function where $f(x) \geq 0$ and the integral of $f$ is $0$.

I am struggling to see the larger *point* here if it's clear to anyone else. Is a sufficient answer to the question the singleton point ${x_0}$ and as a result, the condition is satisfied. Unless we take the definition of an interval to need more than one point, which in that case, then I'm unsure.

Comment: Please write complete sentences when you ask a question.  I will edit this grammatically *for you*, but you need to start raising the quality of the questions you ask.

Comment: Use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find $I$ you simply take $\varepsilon=c/2$ and apply the definition of continuity. The point is that, if $f$ is Riemann integrable with $f(x)\geq0$ and $f(x)>M$ on some open interval of length $L$, then you can show that the integral of $f$ is at least $LM$. Hence if $f$ has integral $0$, then such an interval should not exist.

EDIT: After reading your comment again, I realised that $I$ might be taken as $[x_0,x_0]$ which is completely useless. If you specify that $I$ must be open, this makes a lot more sense.

Comment: The question just states "interval" so it's a bit unclear but given that it mentions the function being continuous, guessing applying the definition is the intended approach.

Comment: I expect the question was supposed to ask for an open interval, or at least an interval of positive length, but the writer simply forgot to add this condition. This is more common than you might think.